# General Questions About Joint Control (Gazebo & ROS2)

Tags: gazebo, ros2, torque, gazebo-ros-control

There are some separate questions about the Gazebo and ROS 2.

- When I apply force/torque to a link about its joint in Gazebo simulation by hand, it behaves different than the one that is controlled from ROS 2. I am using **effort_controllers** from **libgazebo_ros2_control.so**. Applying torque in Gazebo simulation rotates the link (robot leg in my case), but applying effort to it makes the robot fly in sky. What could be the reason? Wrong inertia, wrong controller or effort is not the same as torque etc.?
- Gazebo sim tutorials and plugin explanations/guides are very insufficient (eg, https://gazebosim.org/docs). Is there a way to learn and use both the Gazebo and ROS 2 together efficiently? (Even if it is a paid option)
- When using different open-source packages, there is always some version conflicts. For example, some packages support ROS but not ROS 2 or it works for some version of ROS 2 but cannot be utilized with other distributions of ROS 2. How to overcome this if there is a workaround?

Thank you,
Selim

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (specifically, a single specific problem. this should ideally be 3 unique, specific questions, posted independently of each other.)